# Don't kill process when dotnet project shut down

Tags: c#, .net, linux, process, parent-child

I'm working on a dotnet app for a Linux system (debian). I want to run commands on Linux from my app. I'm running commands using this method. I really don't want to change it if possible.

```
public static async Task<Process> RunCommandAsync(string command)
{
    string cmd = command.Replace("\"", "\\\"");
    Process process = new()
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "/bin/bash",
            Arguments = $"-c \"{cmd}\"",
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
        }
    };
    process.Start();
    await process.WaitForExitAsync();
    return process;
}
```

My goal is to start a process within the project and not killing it when I shut down the project. I wanted to use only a command. I tried something like this `sudo nohup sh -c 'ping google.com' > /dev/null &`, which I though that would work but when I shut down the project the process is also terminated.

In short, in this example I wanted to continuing the ping even after I shut down the project.

### Edit 1

Here, for simplicity, I gave the example of a ping. In reality the app is in a debian package and there are two apps running at the same time, both as services. At some point I want in uninstall the app, which stops both services. I stop the service responsible for this first, and then the other service is never stop and the app isn't uninstalled correctly.

Comment: Setting `UseShellExecute = true` should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't work. If I run it like that it doesn't start a process (at least i dont see it with htop) and if I try to read the output it gives me an error `System.InvalidOperationException: The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to redirect IO streams`

Comment: That the next problem. Redirection makes only sense if you have a recipient for that. So if you want an independent process you can't redirect. The recipient of the output must live longer than the creator of the output.

Comment: @Ralf Yeah the read output was just a small test to check if there was anything happening. But the problem continues. It still doesn't do anything. I call the method and the ping doesn't show up in htop

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119648/redirecting-to-dev-null

Comment: @Tudeschizieuinchid I dont think so. Here the problem is the process stopping when the project is shut down. Here I gave the ping as an example, in reality in my project I uninstall the app from my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I created a service (finish.service) like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Uninstall app1 and install app2  

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/opt/finish/finish.sh
WorkingDirectory=/opt/finish/
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal
```

Where "/opt/finish/finish.sh": (simplified code)

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt purge app1;
sudo apt install app2;
```

In my app, when I want to uninstall it and install a new one I simply call

```
sudo systemctl start finish.service
```